# Pythonic way to separate operators and operands in an expression

Tags: python

I am trying to separate the operators (including parentheses) and the operands in an expression. For example given an expression

```
expr = "(32+54)*342-(4*(3-9))"
```

I am trying to get

```
['(', '32', '+', '54', ')', '*', '342', '-', '(', '4', '*', '(', '3', '-', '9', ')', ')']
```

Here is the code that I wrote. Is there a better way of doing it in python.

```
l = list(expr)
n = ''
expr = []
try:
  for c in l:
    if c in string.digits:
      n += c
    else:
      if n != '':
        expr.append(n)
        n = ''
      expr.append(c)
finally:
  if n != '':
    expr.append(n)
```

Comment: There's no need for `try ... finally`. Just do `for c in l: ...; if n != '': expr.append(n)`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Apart from being a cool and practical example of the concept of abstract syntax trees, it's not exactly relevant. After all, OP is not trying to implement (or even just parse) Python or a subset of Python recognizable as such.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> expr = "(32+54)*342-(4*(3-9))"
>>> re.split("([-()+*/])", expr)
['', '(', '32', '+', '54', ')', '', '*', '342', '-', '', '(', '4', '*', '', '(', '3', '-', '9', ')', '', ')', '']
```

This does insert some empty strings, but these can probably be handled or stripped out trivially enough. E.g with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp):

```
>>> [part for part in re.split("([-()+*/])", expr) if part]
['(', '32', '+', '54', ')', '*', '342', '-', '(', '4', '*', '(', '3', '-', '9', ')', ')']
```

Comment: Of course, this falls down for less trivial tokens. For example, it fails the second you have multi-character operators.

Comment: @delnan Indeed, but for the example given, it does the job.

Comment: Yes, and I'm not exactly complaining. It does this job, we just need to be aware that it doesn't scale to similar, but more complex tasks.

Comment: Well, you could use a regular expression with a ton of ``|`` (or) cases to handle multi-character operators. Not pretty, but it'd work.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the use of `split`. Regular expressions are certainly useful for tackling much more complicated problems, only you'd repeatedly apply a huge regex (or try a large number of regexes in turn), not try to split everything in one pass.

Comment: @delnan Unless the OP is doing something very intensive with this, it's likely not to matter, and this is the simplest answer. Obviously, where performance is critical, it may not be the best approach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17009/discussion-between-delnan-and-lattyware)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to tokenize the stream, your approach is fine, but somewhat old-fashioned. You can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), to split the tokens more easily.

However, if you also want to do something with the tokens (such as evaluate them) then I suggest you look at a parsing module that can handle recursion (regular expressions cannot handle recursion), such as [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: Even when doing proper parsing, many approaches *require* you to tokenize first, and even with scannerless parsers it's still a great first pass to simplify the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Python: [Batteries Included](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html).

```
>>> [x[1] for x in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO.StringIO('(32+54)*342-(4*(3-9))').readline)]
['(', '32', '+', '54', ')', '*', '342', '-', '(', '4', '*', '(', '3', '-', '9', ')', ')', '']
```

Comment: That tokenizes by Python rules. Which is great if you're parsing Python or something Python-like, but in this case it's a mere coincidence it applies. It's like using `sum` to concatenate lists.

Comment: @delnan: "By Python rules" is... fairly broad though. Since it only tokenizes and not parses, it has no problem with constructs such as `'1 2 + 3 *'`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's still using something where it is more coincidence that the solution matches. That's a little hackish - and most importantly, I think it makes it less clear what is going on in the code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Precisely, it's far too broad. The syntax in the question is simple enough to be valid Python, but that does not mean it makes sense to use Python tools, because those implement a far more complicated language. For instance, `tokenize` has no problems with `def[...] ~= @(*'')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> if True:
    exp=[]
    expr = "(32+54)*342-(4*(3-9))"
    flag=False
    for i in expr:
        if i.isdigit() and flag:
            exp.append(str(exp.pop(len(exp)-1))+i)
        elif i.isdigit():
            flag=True
            exp.append(i)
        else:
            flag=False
            exp.append(i)
    print(exp)


['(', '32', '+', '54', ')', '*', '342', '-', '(', '4', '*', '(', '3', '-', '9', ')', ')']
>>>
```